How to put multiple conditions to auto check the radio button in ASP.NET MVC cshtml
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.authType, "email", Model.authType == "email")Email
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.authType, "sms", Model.authType == "sms")SMS

In the above code, the radio button is auto checked based on condition Model.authType == "email" or Model.authType == "sms", but I want to add two conditions to auto check the radio button.
For example I tried to add condition like
Model.authType == "email" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.email) 

But the second condition is not executed, and the checkbox is auto checking based on first condition and ignoring the second condition.
It's working fine if I use only a single condition.
I tried this code but it's not working:
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.authType, "email", Model.authType == "email" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.email) )Email

@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.authType, "sms", Model.authType == "sms" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.phone) )SMS

I also tried to assign both those condition in a single Boolean variable and used that variable but still not working.

I have codes below, and per my test, whether or not I have codes like Model.IsEnrolled== "All", the radio button for All will always be selected. The same if I set Model.IsEnrolled== "Yes", the radio button for Yes will be selected. I think you can put the validation in your controller instead of your cshtml. You might have codes similar to mine which setting value for authType like model.authType == !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.email) ? "email" : "sms". Then when email is null, the sms radio button would be checked. Anyway, it depends on your own business logic.
<form asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <p>
        Title: <input type="text" asp-for="SearchString" />
        Gender:
        <span class="col-md-10">
            <span style="margin-left:10px;">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsEnrolled, "Yes") Enrolled
            </span>
            <span style="margin-left:10px;">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsEnrolled, "No") Not Enrolled
            </span>
            <span style="margin-left:10px;">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsEnrolled, "All") All
            </span>
        </span>
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
</form>

public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string isEnrolled)
{
    var movies = from m in _context.Movie
                 select m;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(isEnrolled))
    {
        movies = movies.Where(x => x.Genre == "asdf");
    }
    var movieGenreVM = new MovieGenreViewModel
    {
        Movies = await movies.ToListAsync(),
        IsEnrolled = string.IsNullOrEmpty(isEnrolled) ? "All" : isEnrolled
    };
    return View(movieGenreVM);
}

